# Table won't load

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I can see the array in the console but it doesnt show up on the table i've tried alot of things and it just hasnt worked out and i've been trying to fix this for like 2 days
i think tobodyHtml doesnt get defined but i dont know how to fix it

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
function loadUsers(){
var userTbody=document.getElementById('user-tbody');
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
         var userJSON=this.responseText;
         var usersArray=JSON.parse(userJSON);
         console.log(usersArray);
         var tobodyHtml="";
         for(let index = 0; index < usersArray.lenght; index++) {
             const user = usersArray[index];
             tobodyHtml+="<tr><td>"+user.id+"</td><td>"+user.username+"</td><td>"+user.password+"</td><td>"+user.birthdate+"</td></tr>";
             console.log(tobodyHtml);
         }
         userTbody.innerHTML=tobodyHtml;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8279/users", true);
    xhttp.send();

}
loadUsers();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/trgames.css">
          
           <meta charset="utf-8">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.11.5/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-8cU710tp3iH9RniUh6fq5zJsGnjLzOWLWdZqBMLtqaoZUA6AWIE34lwMB3ipUNiTBP5jEZKY95SfbNnQ8cCKvA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
           <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
           <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </head>
     <body>
      
        <table id="user-table">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>Id</th>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Password</th>
                   <th>Birthday</th>
               </tr>
           </thead> 
           <tbody id="user-tbody">

          </tbody>
        </table>
        <script src="js/trgames.js"></script>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".

Comment: typo `lenght` should be `length`

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue before and I find that when creating HTML elements in JavaScript, it's best to use dom `document.createElement` to create the elements then add the inner text. Then you can append the final data into the body. Here's a simplified version of your code without the HTTP request since I don't have that data handy. There were also a few minor typos in your for loop (length) and some other issues that I cleaned up.

```
// grab refs to our html elements
const userTbody = document.getElementById("user-tbody");
const tr = document.createElement("tr");

// test data
const usersArray = [
    {
        id: 23,
        username: "Joe",
        password: "123",
        birthdate: "01/01/2018"
    }
];

// event on dom content loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    // loop through data of users
    usersArray.forEach((user) => {
        
        // simple pattern to create the td and place the data on it
        const userIdData = document.createElement("td")
        userIdData.innerText = user.id
        
        const userNameData = document.createElement("td")
        userNameData.innerText = user.username;
        
        const userPasswordData = document.createElement("td")
        userPasswordData.innerText = user.password
        
        const userBirthdateData = document.createElement("td")
        userBirthdateData.innerText = user.birthdate
        
    // append all of the data we created to the tbody
        userTbody.append(
            userIdData, 
            userNameData, 
            userPasswordData, 
            userBirthdateData
        );
    })
})
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/LTFoReal/pen/VwQqjKg?editors=1111) example

Comment: ok thanks for the answer but do i put this all in the XMLhttprequest if?

Comment: oh the problem was the typo :)

Comment: yeah it's usually something simple like a typo haha.. you can drop all of this into your XMLHTTP request if you would like though. I think it's easier to read/modify.